# Moodle Add a new block as Admin for all users , to appear on all pages

Tags: moodle

I have a created a simple custom block that outputs Html. I want to add it in front page context with page->context "Display throughout the entire site". I googled and found the procedure :

- As an administrator, turn on the editing on the front page and add the block you wish to make sticky.
- For Where this block appears>Page contexts, choose 'Display throughout the entire site'.
- Decide other settings according to your preference and save.
- The block will now appear on all pages of your Moodle.

I am just not able to add the block with context front page.
Hence, I do not get "Display throughout the entire site".

Also it is not added for students and teachers.

Please help.

Moodle version : 2.8.5

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the front page and not /my/ page?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I am new to moodle. In my project the "Default home page for users" is set as "My Home page". The actual first page has sliders, no moodle content. After login the user lands on "My Home/My Courses". I need the block on this page...

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add this to `class block_yourblockname` in `/blocks/yourblockname/block_yourblockname.php`

```
function applicable_formats() {
    return array('all' => true);
}
```

Applicable formats restricts the block so it only appears on certain pages.

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks#Authorized_Personnel_Only

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried but it still adds only for admin user , on My Home page. As Jakub Kania above mentioned,  I am actually trying add on page "My Home > My Courses" and the url is "/my"...

Comment: Do you have any content in the block? If there is no content then only admin users will see the block. Try this  `function get_content() { $this->content = new stdClass(); $this->content->text = 'some content'; return $this->content; }`

Comment: I do have content. I have the above code. It is a "Message of the day" block, displays a default message if not set. Message can be set in the block configuration...I guess I am missing something basic. For , i am not able to add blocks as admin visible to students and teachers. Let me point out that the admin has been assigned the role of manager also...

Comment: @Bhargava Ensure you have assigned permission to the desired roles in `db/access.php` for the "addinstance" capability. Also make sure you bump the plugin's version.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question - and after a day of scratching my head, i found the answer.

Because of the setting Site Administration/Navigation/
is set to redirect everyone to dashboard - there is no way to get to the frontpage by typing in the domain name, or clicking on the logo or any normal way one expects to get to the front page except by logging out.

Turns out, there is one more block menu called 'Navigation'. If you've ever clicked the minimize toggle on it, good luck. In that Navigation menu, there is 'Site Home' Even though one would expect that 'Site Home' would probably bring one back to the dashboard again, this one will in fact, bring you to the front page - with full administrative rights.

Hope this helps anyone who is scratching their heads on trying to modify the front page.