# Moodle 2.8.5+:How to set new block access rules?

Tags: php, moodle

I am developing a new block. I added it's instance to the page, but there are two problems:

1. after turn editing off it will disappear.
2. after logging out as a user it will disappear. I think the problem is related to db/access.php

I like the block to be sticky an shown to every body: users, guests, etc. So how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What page are you adding it to? A course's page? The front page? Are you adding it as the administrator user?

Comment: any top category page, I guess I found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288299/moodle-add-a-new-block-as-admin-for-all-users-to-appear-on-all-pages  there's a comment from @Russell England :  Do you have any content in the block? If there is no content then only admin users will see the block.

Comment: I do not know why some one down voted my question! It is a stack over flow question!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the block should return some contents. Empty content results in disappearing the block for non-admin users! Also there is no relation between this question and db/access.php file!